# How to avoid Fishing and DOS attack in Http Mail server

Tags: apache, centos

we are running a http mail server in Centos, few days ago its been attacked by hacker and used to snatch the details from other third party web servers, main issues is, those stolen details were stored into our mail server, now its been identified and server downed. But how could it be possible, is there main configuration need to be done in OS fire wall  or else is there feature available with Apache server to avoid being used it by hackers.Please assist.

Comment: What do you mean by _Apache mail server_? Apache James? Or a regular HTTPD running a webmailer?

Comment: @f_puras, its a HTTPD mail server